# Angular add arbitrary property binding with directive

Tags: angular

I would like to add property binding to an element but with with a directive (I'm using Angular 7).

For example given this element:

```
<div myCustomDirective>This is a test</div>
```

In the implementation of myCustomDirective I would like to add arbitrary property bindings (used by another control):

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  // Add the following property
  // [myBinding]="data"
}
```

So effectively resulting in something like the following:

```
<div myCustomDirective [myBinding]="data">This is a test</div>
```

How can this be accomplished?

**UPDATE**:

My goal is to extend the behavior of another control through custom logic. But instead of creating a whole separate control I would like to add that logic through a directive.

For example, say I want to apply certain property binding based on some condition. Through the directive I can check for that condition and selectively add the property bindings.

**ADDITIONAL UPDATE**:

Apparently it is still not clear so let me further clarify. Pretend you have a 3rd party directive called MakeCoffee. Pretend this directive works with multiple property bindings.  However, it lacks some behavior that you expect. So in order to add that additional behavior/logic you create your own directive which checks for your own custom logic and applies the 3rd party property bindings as necessary.

Comment: [Tell us what your need is, instead of asking for help on what you think is the answer](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @trichetriche fair point, let me update my question

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you simply needing an input?

Comment: Those properties bindings are Angular syntax, which means they are **pre build**. They get compiled into something totally different in JS. If you wish to do that, you can't. Could you provide an example of your need ? It's not that clear to understand to be honest ...

Comment: @trichetriche my need is to add custom logic to an element in the form of property bindings, a directive is Angular syntax which gets executed by Angular, do you not agree?

Comment: Property bindings are angular related. If you want to add an attribute to your tag you don't need a directive.